# php - Convert array values to same values with pipe separated (NOT STRING)

Tags: php, json

I want to convert

```
$json_options = array(
    1, // JSON_HEX_TAG
    2, // JSON_HEX_AMP
    4, // JSON_HEX_APOS
    8, // JSON_HEX_QUOT
);
```

to

```
1 | 2 | 4 | 8
```

to be used in

```
json_encode($data, $json_options);
```

Of course I don't want to implode them to make an string. How to do that?

Comment: *Of course I don't want to implode them to make an string* - can you explain why not, it seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: @NigelRen Because the `json_encode` doesn't accept `$json_options` as string.

Comment: @Ivar Yeah thank you :)